# Insert time and datetime in azure db using C# and AngularJS

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs

right now I am working on a web-site and I need to insert some users into my database using C# for backend and AngularJS for frontend. If I use postman, everything works fine, the routes are good, but I have a problem when I try to insert them via angularJS. Here is my db structure

[image]

**my HTML code**

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="newcandidateController as vm">
<form>
    <div class="myInputs">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="   Full name" id="i1" ng-model="vm.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="   Email" ng-model="vm.email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="   Phone" ng-model="vm.phone">
        </div>

        <p id="username">Username: </p>
        <p id="password">Password: </p>

        <div>
            <p>Position</p>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.position">
                <option ng-repeat="obj in vm.Tests">{{obj.testType}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <br />
            <label>Admin: </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="admin" id="checkbox" ng-model="vm.isadmin">
        </div>

            <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Generate credentials" id="g" ng-click="vm.generate()">
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="vm.postUser()">
    </div>
</form>
```

**and my JavaScript file**

```
        vm.postUser = function () {
        if (vm.position == "SysAdmin") {
            vm.test = 2;
        } else if (vm.position == "Java soft engineer") {
            vm.test = 3;
        } else if (vm.position == "SQL Solutions Architect") {
            vm.test = 4;
        } else {
            vm.test = 5;
        }
        vm.date = "";
        vm.time = "";
        dataContext.addUser(vm.name, vm.email, vm.phone, vm.position, vm.username, vm.password, vm.isadmin, vm.test, vm.date, vm.time).then(
            function (response) {
                console.log(vm.name + " " + vm.email + " " + vm.phone + " " + vm.position + " " + vm.username + " " + vm.password + " " + vm.isadmin + " " + vm.test + " " + vm.date + " " + vm.time);
                alert("It worked!");
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    };
```

I don't know how to define a default value for date and time cuz at first I want them to be 0 and update it later.

Any help would be awesome, thank you!

edit:

Here is method where I post a user

```
    public User CreateUser(User user)
    {
        db.User.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: you also need to post your C# code.  i think the problem is in there

Comment: I don't think so, the controller works fine, I tested it @flbas1

Comment: you could use a tool such as postman to look at the post data and see what differs